# Java LocalDate Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, date

A simple question.  Why am I getting an error - "Text '03-JUL-2010' could not be parsed at index 3" for the following code.  in Java 1.8? Using Eclipse.

If I change the code to the commented section.   It runs just fine.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//      String date         = "2010-Jul-03";
//      String dateformat   = "yyyy-MMM-dd";

    String date         = "03-JUl-2010";
    String dateformat   = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

    LocalDate localizeddate = LocalDate.parse(date,    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateformat));

    System.out.println(localizeddate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Build](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) that [ignores case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseInsensitive--)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                     .parseCaseInsensitive()
                     .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateformat))
                     .toFormatter();
```

Or fix the upper/lowercase in month name, editing `JUl` to be `Jul`.

```
String date         = "03-Jul-2010";
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Did not realize that case would be the issue.

Comment: @userDSSR Note that `Locale` and the language of the month (or day of week, etc.) also matter.